# Dragon for Salesforce

Tags: appexchange

Just downloaded the Dragon for SFDC app which works fine outside of the office, but once in the office I keep getting this error message:
"Cannot connect to our system. Please make sure that you have an Internet connection".
I do indeed have an Internet connection as I can access the web and other apps on my Ipad but we do have a proxy server. Is there any place where I can set the proxy? Seems like that is what is causing the issue. Could not find this in settings. 
Anyone ever encounter this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to contact provider of that app. Odds are higher they have support or developers who can answer you than anyone here having experience with that app.